# Where to find the Oracle EBS Form for fnd_document_categories in EBS 12.2

Tags: oracle-ebs

In previous versions of Oracle EBS one could use the Application Developer responsibility (no longer exists in 12.2) to define custom Document Categories for use with Form Attachment file uploads using the navigation path Application Developer –> Attachments –> Document Categories

This would then create a custom Document Category in `fnd_document_categories`

How can the same be done in Oracle EBS 12.2?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle did not remove the Application Developer responsibility in 12.2. If you do not see it, then there is apparently non standard setup in your environment.
The Document Categories form also exists in other menus, for example Order Management-> Setup-> Orders-> Attachments-> Document Categories.

If you are looking for all responsibilities and menu paths from which a specific form can be accessed, you can use the SQL query from blitz report [FND Access Control](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/fnd-access-control/).